# restrict url redirecting using RewriteRule name .htaccess

Tags: php

i have check-login.php to prevent accessing the certain page using url
but it doesn't work when i type the `RewriteRule` name

example i type in the `URL: domain/user-home.php`, check-login.php works
but when i type `URL: domain/home`check-login.php is not readable/working

i used .htaccess to rewrite the name of my php file this is my code

```
RewriteRule ^home?$ user-home.php
```

my question is when i type RewriteRule name in URL restriction is not working which is my check-login.php, and it applies only on php file name like the mention above `user-home.php`

check-login.php code:

```
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['LOGIN'])
{
    exit(include('error2.php'));
}
// this code is included in user-home.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited the code here. Best approach would be like this.

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^POST$
RewriteRule ^php/check-login.php$ - [NC,R=404,L]
```

this should redirect to the 404file not found .

Comment: i dont have problem for session code i have problem with the URL

Comment: yup when i type php file name restriction is work, but when rewriterule name it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

this is another way of doing things.
you shoud have 404.php on the root directory.

```
RewriteRule ^404/?$ 404.php
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/404/
```